# Stored procedures in EF 6.1.3

Tags: c#, entity-framework, t-sql, stored-procedures, ef-code-first

I'm new to Entity Framework and have ran into a problem. 
I have created a stored procedure in the DB (in SMMS) and triggering from .NET works fine.

However I would like EF to feed the SP to the database if the DB is wiped (like the seed method fills in data). Also I would like to have my SP in vertion control with the rest of my codebase.
So, how do I add the SP to my project in a way that it will be created with the DB, I guess its like a migration, but with no direct connection to a model class.

Is it possible to generate a "empty" migration and then modify it to my needs? with up and down method that creates and removes the SP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible to generate an empty migration and then modify it to your needs. In package manager `Add-Migration "AddMyStoredProcedure"`

Then in your Up method:

```
Sql(@"EXECUTE('CREATE PROCEDURE MyStoredProcedure...etc ");
```

And in your Down method:

```
Sql(@"EXECUTE('DROP PROCEDURE MyStoredProcedure')");
```

I tend to use the [`Sql`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.data.entity.migrations.dbmigration.sql(v=vs.113).aspx) method, but there are also [`CreateStoredProcedure`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.data.entity.migrations.dbmigration.createstoredprocedure(v=vs.113).aspx) and [`DropStoredProcedure`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.data.entity.migrations.dbmigration.dropstoredprocedure(v=vs.113).aspx) methods in the `DbMigration` class that you may prefer

Comment: How could I miss that. Thanks a lot, just what I needed.